# Where do I ask questions related to PC/notebook upgrading?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about upgrading the notebook RAM.

I have a question about RAM slots. Where can I post it?

Would that be *on-topic* at SE Super User or SE Electrical engineering?

Comment: Are you looking for a recommendation on what type of ram to get?

Comment: @Andy no, i cant figure out where are the 2 slots on motherboard, which were installed with ram planks by the manufacturer, so i want to ask if someone done this specific notebook model upgrading, and can help me

Comment: You should read the site policies first. I don't believe it would be really _on-topic _ at Electrical Engineering.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `Markdown parser error: underscore is not a valid marker, did you mean *?`

Comment: @rene "did you mean *?" Probably a typo, I meant _italics_ for emphasis. But not there :-P

Comment: Look in the user or maintenance manual for your notebook.

Comment: The question in theory is on topic at Superuser, the problem your going to have is the fact, the instructions are in a manual.  So the answer you would recieve would be to read the manual, and perhaps the body of this answe would provide you the instructions, but the question wouldn't be well recieved.  You are expected to do a certain amoutn of research before asking a question, and reading the instructions to install user replacable memory, is one of those things you should do before asking this question.  Once you do that, quote what you don't understand, that would be well recieved.

Answer (score 2):

It's on topic on Super User to an *extent*.

> i cant figure out where are the 2 slots on motherboard, which were installed with ram planks by the manufacturer, so i want to ask if someone done this specific notebook model upgrading, and can help me

Has anyone done this? Maybe, but that's not a good question.

How do I do this? With examples of what you looked at, and enough information that someone technical who has never seen your laptop before can guess? Yeah, it would be an awesome fit. In a sense, if you've tried the logical things, and are really stuck, sure - it's on topic on Super User.

Chances are though - someone would point you at the service manual.